# Census taking off the grid

Tags: xml

We're writing software for child sponsorship organizations that need to collect data in remote villages (no electricity).  Our idea is to use a small device to enter childrens' names and when the agent gets back to an Internet cafe, they can upload the data.

Our thought is to use an XML file to store the data.
What device can you recommend for doing this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to work through some logistical constraints. How long will the agent be without power? Does the device need to be dust-proof/waterproof/drop-proof? How much data is being collected at a time?

Comment: 24 hours.
Dust-Proof: Yes
WaterProof: Water resistant
Drop proof: No

1000 names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a TomTom GPS with an SD Card and store each child as a favourite and then extract the info from the SD Card on a smart phone, or write a custom plugin for the TomTom to sync over bluetooth via a smartphone.

---

Edit:

It's also just occurred to me that an Android device may be more suitable because of the longer battery life. Obviously you'd need to write a custom application to capture the info - whereas the TT you could use out of the box. Either way having something with a GPS receiver  could help.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of an Android pad.